# cfgutil no longer works via ssh after upgrading to Sierra

Tags: ssh, macos, apple-configurator

I use the `cfgutil` from Apple Configurator with iOS devices on an OSX host via SSH. After upgrading to Sierra, I get a NSCocoaErrorDomain message and it fails. It works fine at the terminal, however.

Here's my output of trying it successfully at a local terminal, then sshing and the failure:

```
~ cfgutil list
Type: [...] ECID: [...] UDID: [...] Location: [...] Name: [...]
~  ssh localhost /usr/local/bin/cfgutil list
Password:
cfgutil: error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.configurator.xpc.InternetService" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.configurator.xpc.InternetService}
```

I assume this comes from some increased security measures from Sierra, but for me it's a pain. Any ideas how to disable this or work around it?

Comment: I see the same thing, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a slightly better workaround now:

```
sudo /bin/launchctl asuser 0 cfgutil list
```

Don't ask me how it works, but I get expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very awkward workaround, though input is hidden:

- Create a file, e.g. `/tmp/cfgutil.sh` on the server
- Populate that file with the command you wish to run, e.g. `cfgutil list`
- When you ssh in, run `open -a Terminal /tmp/cfgutil.sh`

Here's a minimal example:
`echo "/usr/local/bin/cfgutil list" > /tmp/cfgutil.sh && ssh localhost open -a Terminal "/tmp/cfgutil.sh"`

I suspect it only works if the user is logged in via the UI as well.